# How to extract maximum value coordinates from ParametricPlot of function

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions, maximum

I have a [`ParametricPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html)

```
ParametricPlot[{Sin[x], 2 Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 π}]
```

**How to know the maximum value on *Y-axix* and X-axis?**

Comment: Do you really need to extract the information from the `ParametricPlot` or is it OK to extract it from the equation? Please [edit] your question to clarify. Learn about [good questions here](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3).

Answer (score 2):

```
x /. Solve[D[Sin[x], x]==0, x]
```

will find `x`, then just plug it into `Sin[x]`.  Of course this will give either a maximum or minimum.  Select the maximum.

Or use the second-derivative text from calculus.

Answer (score 0):

### From Plot

To extract from the plot itself you can do

```
pplt = ParametricPlot[{Sin[x], 2 Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 π}];

Max /@ (PlotRange /. Options[pplt])
(* {1., 2.} *)
```

### From equation

```
First /@ Thread@Maximize[{Sin[x], 2 Cos[x]}, x]

(* {1, 2} *)
```

or with constraints and maxima positions

```
Maximize[{#, 0 < x < 2 π}, x] & /@ {Sin[x], 2 Cos[x]}

(* {{1, {x -> π/2}}, {2, {x -> 0}}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks. How we can use the range of x, to get maxima from function.

Comment: You can specify constraints in `Maximize`. If your question requieres **clarification**, please edit your question. But if you have a **follow-up question**, then you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Ypu can also use `PlotRange` as a function:

```
plot = ParametricPlot[{Sin[x], 2 Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]

Max /@ PlotRange @ plot
```

> {1., 2.}